# HTTP POST using CURL in Linux

Tags: java, linux, http, post, curl

Help needed on finding corresponding curl command syntax corresponding to below java code which works.

Working Java Code>

```
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("/SEMP");
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic U1ZDLlNPTFJPRTE6anVXMmFfdVc=");

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("<rpc>command</rcp>", "UTF-8"); stringEntity.setContentType("text/xml");
    httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity)stringEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, (HttpRequest)httppost, localcontext);
```

Corresponding Curl Syntax needed?
Please help on corresponding syntax for curl

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check `curl` man page. Especially [-u](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-u) section.

Comment: Didin't quite work shantanoo. Also no username or password used here. You can see in above java code. I have tried multiple options such as below

1. curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Authorization: Basic U1ZDLlNPTFJPRTE6anVXMmFfdVc=" -d@commandfilename http://targethost.com
2. curl -vX POST -F 'Authorization=Basic U1ZDLlNPTFJPRTE6anVXMmFfdVc=' -F 'command' http://targethost.com

and few more. none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

General curl command worked. I missed specifying the URI while calling targetURL.

Working Command Syntax

curl -vX POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -H "Authorization: Basic U1ZDLlNPTFJPRTE6anVXMmFfdVc=" -d 'command' http://targethost.com/URI

Thanks.

Thanks